# I am having trouble calling a product from the database. (MongoDb - Nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, backend

When I typed phone in the search box, I found and fetched all categories with the word phone in the database. Then I wanted to find the products by matching the _id number of this category with the category id number of the product. but I cannot collect the products I find in a single array. that's why I can't print them all on the screen. Since two different arrays are created in the arrays, it prints the products in the first arrays, but does not pass to the second arrays.

[array in array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2E0bx.png)

As you can see from the picture, I cannot print it because the 3rd product is in the other array.

```js
function escapeRegex(text) {
    return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
};

let model = [];
const searchRegex = new RegExp(escapeRegex(req.query.search), 'gi');
  SubSubCategory.find({ "name": searchRegex})
      .then(subsubcategoriesProduct => {
          subsubcategoriesProduct.forEach(p => {
              Product.find({ categories: p._id })
              .then(finalProduct => {
                  model.push(finalProduct);
                  res.render('shop/products', {
                      title: 'Tüm Ürünler',
                      products: model,
                      path: '/products',
                      searchRegex: searchRegex
                  });
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are 50 products in `subsubcategoriesProduct`, you are consequently launching 50 new Mongo queries at once inside the `forEach`. Each of these `Product.find` operations is asynchronous and will complete some time later, triggering 50 `res.render`. You can't do that, you can only have one `res.render`.

Dealing with this kind of things using the traditional `.then()` syntax is complicated and easily leads to a callback hell (then inside then inside then). Using `await` instead of `.then()` makes things way easier.

Also, instead of making 50 queries (one for each _id) you should make one query with an array of _id.

```
const subcategories = await SubSubCategory.find({ name: searchRegex}, '_id')
                                        .lean() // return only JSON, not full Mongoose objects
                                        .exec(); // Returns a Promise so we can use await on it

const ids = subcategories.map(s => s._id);

const model = await Product.find({ categories: { $in : ids } }).lean().exec();

res.render('shop/products', {
                title: 'Tüm Ürünler',
                products: model,
                path: '/products',
                searchRegex: searchRegex
            });
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your informative answer, it really worked for me, i am grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem this way.

```js
function escapeRegex(text) {
    return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
};

exports.getSearch = async (req, res, next) => {
    try{
        const subsubcategories = await SubSubCategory.find();
        const subcategories = await SubCategory.find();
        const categories = await Category.find();
        
        if(req.query.search){
            var searchRegex = new RegExp(escapeRegex(req.query.search), 'gi');
        }

        const subsubcategoriesProduct = await SubSubCategory.find({ "name": searchRegex}, '_id')

        const ids = subsubcategoriesProduct.map(s => s._id);

        const finalProduct = await Product.find({ categories: {$in: ids} });

        res.render('shop/products', {
            title: 'Tüm Ürünler',
            products: finalProduct,
            path: '/products',
            categories: categories,
            subcategories: subcategories,
            subsubcategories: subsubcategories,
            searchRegex: searchRegex,
            inputs:{
                takeSecondHand: '',
                takeMinPrice: '',
                takeMaxPrice: ''
            }
        });
    }
    catch(err){
        next(err);
    }
}
```